# Depending on a browser a label has different inner padding within a div

Tags: html, css

I have a container with an icon and a label inside it. I'm using flexbox to align icon and the label to the bottom of the container.

What I noticed, depending on a browser (Chrome and FF, for example), the distance from the bottom of the container to the text in the label is different by around 1px.

[image]

I played with line-hight and different layouts of icon+label, but I couldn't get rid of this 1px difference.
Icon does not play any role in that layout, but I added it, as because of existence of the icon I care about aligning this pixel.

https://jsfiddle.net/eh7jrp6s/6/

```
<div class="container ng-scope">
  <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDIwIDIwIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTYgMTBINFY3YzAtLjYtLjQtMS0xLTFzLTEgLjQtMSAxdjhjMCAuNi40IDEgMSAxczEtLjQgMS0xdi0zaDEydjNjMCAuNi40IDEgMSAxczEtLjQgMS0xVjdjMC0uNi0uNC0xLTEtMXMtMSAuNC0xIDF2M3oiIGZpbGw9IiMwMGI2ZmYiLz48L3N2Zz4=&quot;);">
  </span>
  <span class="label ng-binding">_________this line is on different level depending on a browser_______</span>
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    color: $blue;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height:18px
  }
    .icon {
      background-size: 2rem 2rem;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      line-height:18px
    }

    .label {
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 1px solid green;
      line-height:18px
    }
```

Any idea how I can equalize the distance to the label from the bottom of the container for different browsers?

Comment: Must admit that i measured it with pixel ruler and couldn't see any particular difference..

Comment: After a long time of testing i find a solution for this issue and i updated my post below plz take a look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785574/7465452)

Answer (score 0):

♦ in your css > inside the `.container{ }` just add :

```
 z-index:0;
```

i test it in 3 browsers > chrome + safari + firefox - and its work in all : [Result](https://jsfiddle.net/eh7jrp6s/21/)

> ☼ Note:  z-index works on positioned elements list like :
>                  ( position:***absolute***, position:***relative***, position:***fixed*** ) or (display: ***flex***).